# Why does N'ko use 3 decimal places for displaying Fixed-Point ("F") numbers while literally every other culture uses 2?

Tags: c#, localization, internationalization, number-formatting

Different cultures use different decimal separators: a dot (1.23) or comma (1,23) or—in the case of Persian (Iran)—a momayyez or slash may be found ([۱٫۲۳](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sxXf.png) or 1/23). I've been testing my library which involves a lot of number parsing (a TimeSpanParser), so have been testing .NET's handling of various numeric formats.

When outputting with the ["F" decimal format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-fixed-point-f-format-specifier) or Numeric ("N") format, all cultures display 2 decimal places except N'Ko ("nqo" or "nqo-GN"). Why is this so?

Code examples below illustrate this, but it is probably **not** necessary to understand or follow the code below to answer this question.

---

Briefly:

```
Console.WriteLine((1.23456).ToString("F", new CultureInfo("en-US"))); // 1.23 (2 dp in every culture other than "nqo" and "nqo-GN")
Console.WriteLine((1.23456).ToString("F", new CultureInfo("nqo"))); // 1.235
```

More verbosely:

```
double number = 1.2345678;

Console.WriteLine($"Testing {number.GetType().FullName}");
Console.WriteLine($"value: {number}");
foreach (var culture in new string[] { "", "en-US", "fr-FR", "fa-IR", "nqo", "nqo-GN" } ) {
    var cultureinfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(culture);
    string fformat = number.ToString("F", cultureinfo);
    Console.WriteLine($"{fformat} -- {cultureinfo.EnglishName} -- \"{cultureinfo.Name}\"");
}
```

Output:

```
Testing System.Double
value: 1.2345678
1.23 -- Invariant Language (Invariant Country) -- ""
1.23 -- English (United States) -- "en-US"
1,23 -- French (France) -- "fr-FR"
1/23 -- Persian (Iran) -- "fa-IR"
1.235 -- N'ko -- "nqo"
1.235 -- N'ko (Guinea) -- "nqo-GN"
```

For the sake of brevity I've only illustrated with one or two cultures for each type of output. I did try searching all cultures from `CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)`, and N'Ko (`nqo` or `nqo-GN`) is the only culture that gave 3 dp.

Note, this is not specific to the `double` type. You'll get similar results if you can also replace the declaration for `number` in the above code with any one of the following lines:

```
float number = 1.2345678f;
decimal number = new decimal(1.2345678);
int number = 1;
BigInteger number = new BigInteger(1);
```

After some research, I guess the issue is down to `NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits` being set to 3 for the N'Ko culture, and 2 for every other culture. But I could not find anything actually stating that this was the case or why it would be the case.

```
Assert.AreEqual(2, new CultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits); // true (for every culture except N'Ko [nqo and nqo-GN])
Assert.AreEqual(3, new CultureInfo("nqo").NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits); // true (for N'Ko)
```

---

Wikipedia's article on the [N'Ko alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N'Ko_alphabet) lists the Unicode characters for N'ko numerals (߀‎߁‎߂‎߃‎߄‎߅‎߆‎߇‎߈‎߉‎) which begin at U+07C0, have a right-to-left directionality and were introduced in Unicode 5 (July 2006). It also has a section on "N'ko and computers", but currently has nothing relevant to this issue. N'Ko numerals do not appear to be used by the Fixed Point format.

**Can anyone give some insight as to why Microsoft has chosen to format this culture's Fixed Point ("F") numbers with a different number of decimal places to every other one of the world's cultures?**

I'm very curious to find out and could not find anything. Is there something special about how N'Ko groups numbers after the decimal place? Is the third decimal place required to display the second one correctly (e.g. due to ligatures or similar)? Or is it Microsoft keeping developers on their toes by making `NumberDecimalDigits` non-static? Or is it a bug? Or is there some other cultural reason?

Comment: Richardissimo, you've given a highly irrelevant response. This relates to Guinea in Africa, not North Korea. The ISO4217 standard, which you have mentioned, relates to currency designators, whereas this question is NOT about currencies. Windows' nqo-GN setting correctly uses 2 decimal places for the currency, as the Guinean franc is divided into 1/100 subunits (centime).

Comment: Apologies, stupid comment deleted. However my main point was that different cultures do things differently. What's the point of asking why it's like that? If you are genuinely asking why that culture uses 3 decimal places, then that is off topic for a software development forum.

Comment: Sorry that you misunderstood the question. If you read beyond the title this time, you might see that I'm specifically asking why Microsoft's cultureinfo implementation uses 3 decimal places. If you understand that to be because the N'Ko culture itself also does, then please explain in what way that is the case and give evidence so I can award you the bounty.

Comment: You're asking whether Microsoft's definition is correct or mistaken. To answer that, someone would simply need to definitively state what the correct value for that culture is - and that would be the only way of supplying an answer. I am simply highlighting that **that** is off topic for a programming forum.

Comment: As best I can tell you're simply arguing for the sake of it.

Comment: I'm genuinely not arguing for the sake of it. For example: Explain how I can answer the question without giving you evidence of the correct value for that culture. You even asked for that evidence yourself in your previous comment.

Comment: Please read the full question.

Comment: It's a fascinating question - trying to track it down.  Here's my favorite theory - someone at Microsoft wanted to make sure the code for the number of decimals worked, so, since they were all 2, he or she wanted to pick a locale to make 3, and N'Ko struck their fancy...

Answer (score 4):

i've been digging through the .net code and found how the cultures are instantiated and created, and defaults are set in your windows. 
So you can see the defaults by going to your regional settings. If you choose nqo you will see that the default for No. digits after decimal is 3, hence .NET is returning you the 3 instead of 2.

See screenshot:

[image]

i know it is not really an answer on your how, but you now know why.

i was fascinated why and googled on it for a while, the only thing i found was this link, i used this term in google: "n'ko" numbers, and the second link is this http://www.languagesandnumbers.com/how-to-count-in-mandinka/en/mnk/ it is about mandinka numbers, a system used in guinea

then some more digging i found calculator:

https://github.com/ckairaba/calculator-nko

maybe by using that you will have some more info